# Using the native memory through java

Tags: android, heap-memory, bytebuffer, unmanaged-memory

Sometimes, it's needed to bypass the heap memory limit of the app and use more than it allows.

I've thought of a solution which will include a caching mechanism that will store bytes in the native memory (not in the heap memory, but the unmanaged memory).

Of course, I will take into account the max available size of the system.

So, knowing a bit about [direct buffers](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/nio_buffer_direct.shtml), I used this to store a bytes array in the native memory:

```
  final ByteBuffer nativeBytes=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bytes.length);
  nativeBytes.put(bytes);
```

However, it seems like on Android, the memory used for this is used in the heap and not in the native memory.

What is going on? Is there an easy alternative for storing & loading data from the native memory?

Comment: There is no such thing as "native memory"; memory has no understanding of native vs. bytecode.  This makes your question very unclear.

Comment: there is managed memory and unmanaged memory . the managed memory has a limit of about 48MB and when you pass it you get OOM exception . the unmanaged memory is about the size of the device's RAM , yet you have to take care of releasing it . such a thing is available when using NDK or OpenGL .

Comment: I wouldn't call this easy (thus worthy as a comment perhaps but not an answer), but from your description it sounds like you could create a class with native methods, where those native methods perform malloc() and free(). If your description of how the DalvikVM manages memory is correct, this should allow you to bypass the DVM check (assuming Android is not taking active steps to inhibit this). The problem to be solved would then be how to access that memory from Java.

Comment: i would assume that java will have to either provide an inputStream or a new byte array with the data that was stored in the native memory . anyway , how do i do implement such a thing? is there already a third part library that does it ?

Comment: "However, it seems like on Android, the memory used for this is used in the heap and not in the native memory" -- how have you determined this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something using NDK that will allocate memory in the native heap for you and communicate with it using JNI. The native parts are implemented in C and use `malloc()` calls to allocate memory in the native heap. You will still be subject to the per-process heap maximum though.

Here's another alternative. Instead of trying to use the native-heap in your own process, just use the dalvik-heap in another process.

Create a service and run the service in another process. You can send data back and forth between your service and the rest of your application. The heap-limits are **per-process** so this effectively doubles the amount of memory your application can use.

Of course, this may not help in your particular case, but it is nice to know that this option is available.

Comment: mallocs are subject to heap limit too?! not only that i've heard it's the opposite , but why would you suggest it if it doesn't help ? also , isn't there an easier way to do it? using multiple processes might not help , since i need relatively quick access to the data , and using intents for this is not very recommended , especially when using large bytes arrays. cool tip though.

Comment: mallocs are subject to the native heap limits, not the dalvik heap limits (as far as I know, but I haven't actually verified that - sorry if it is incorrect). You can get data from another process using synchronous calls to bound services pretty quickly. I've built applications that work like this and it works just fine.

Comment: i probably didn't understand you : what are the native heap limits? about the service , is it as fast as getting the data from the same process?